# Dataframe with predicted values from a classifier

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I would like to know how to create a new pandas dataframe with new emails with their predicted value.
I used the following model:

```
import string

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Email': [
"Hi, I am Andrew and I want too buy VIAGRA",
"Dear subscriber, your account will be closed",
"Please click below to verify and access email restore",
"Hi Anne, I miss you so much! Can’t wait to see you",
"Dear Professor Johnson, I was unable to attend class today",
"I am pleased to inform you that you have won our grand prize.",
"I can’t help you with that cuz it’s too hard.",
"I’m sorry to tell you but im sick and will not be able to come to class.",
"Can I see an example before all are shipped or will that cost extra?",
"I appreciate your assistance and look forward to hearing back from you.",], 
'Spam': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]})

def fun(text):    
    # Removing Punctuations
    remove_punc = [c for c in text if c not in string.punctuation]
    remove_punc = ''.join(remove_punc)

    # Removing StopWords
    cleaned = [w for w in remove_punc.split() if w.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')]

    return cleaned

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=fun)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Email'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, df['Spam'], test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)
classifier = MultinomialNB()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Given a list of new emails:

```
new_email = ["Hi, my name is Christopher", "Buy this movie at a great price!!!", "Should we meet?"]
```

I would like to create a new dataframe which contains these emails and the predicted value:

```
Email                                 Spam
Hi, my name is Christopher             1
Buy this movie at a great price!!!     1
University of London: meeting request  0
```

What I have done for one email was the following:

```
X_new = vectorizer.transform(fun(new_email))

and predicted as follows:
classifier.predict(X_new)
```

However I would need a dataframe like that one above.
Can you please give me some help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `fun()` in your `X_new` assignment cures the problem. You don't need that because `fun` was already assigned as the `analyzer` in the constructor of your `vectorizer`.

**Code**

```
new_email = [
    "Hi, my name is Christopher", 
    "Buy this movie at a great price!!!",
    "Should we meet?"
]

X_new = vectorizer.transform(new_email)

pred_new = classifier.predict(X_new)

pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Email": new_email,
        "Spam": pred_new
    }
)
```

**Output**

```
                                Email  Spam
0          Hi, my name is Christopher     0
1  Buy this movie at a great price!!!     0
2                     Should we meet?     0
```

N.B.1. The predicted spam result differs slightly from your post (row 0, 1), but the whole procedure should be intact. Replacing sentences with previously trained samples shows that the model was working correctly. I am not sure whether this is caused by the inherent randomness in the training process.

Comment: thank you so much Bill Huang. Really appreciated your help